# How to have table in Shiny filled by user?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I want users of my Shiny app to fill in the values of a 2x2 table with row and column names. Of course, I could do it with 4 input boxes, but I assume that it will be tricky to position everything neatly. Despite that, I would prefer a table layout such as the one provided by the `DT` package. Thus, my question is: Is it possible to have a `datatable` (or something similar) filled by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `DT`:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(as.character(numericInput("x11", "", 0)), as.character(numericInput("x21", "", 0))),
  V2 = c(as.character(numericInput("x21", "", 0)), as.character(numericInput("x22", "", 0)))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(5, DT::dataTableOutput('my_table')),
    column(2),
    column(5, verbatimTextOutput("test"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    dat, selection = "none", 
    options = list(searching = FALSE, paging=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, dom="t"), 
    server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, rownames= FALSE, colnames=c("", ""), 
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                  var $this = $(this.node());
                  $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                  $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
                  });
                  Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                  Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
  )

  output$test <- renderText({
    as.character(input$x11)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `shinysky`

`devtools::install_github("AnalytixWare/ShinySky")` package

or `rhandsontable` to do what you want:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinysky)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Initiate your table
  previous <- reactive({mtcars[1:10,]})

  MyChanges <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$hotable1)){return(previous())}
    else if(!identical(previous(),input$hotable1)){
      # hot.to.df function will convert your updated table into the dataframe
      as.data.frame(hot.to.df(input$hotable1))
    }
  })
  output$hotable1 <- renderHotable({MyChanges()}, readOnly = F)
  output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(MyChanges())
})

ui <- basicPage(mainPanel(column(6,hotable("hotable1")),column(6,DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Where to find the `shinysky` package? `install.packages("shinysky")` says it is not found.

Comment: `devtools::install_github("AnalytixWare/ShinySky")`